# Disable gesture listener on DrawerLayout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

How can I disable the gesture recognition for the DrawerLayout? (swipe left to right) and only accept the close gesture (right to left) and open the drawer just with the home button?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

This worked for me:

```js
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

You can expand the drawer by tapping the Home button, and can use right-to-left swipe gesture to dismiss it. However, left-to-right swipe is no longer triggered.

Comment: For unlocking it u use mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);

Comment: This is not working in my case, I always get a drawer on swipe gesture even if I set the Drawer Layout with the above Solution.

Comment: I am having that same issue.

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani and reid-mac  check out Vit-Vetal's answer below.

Comment: It also disabled the close gesture and the back button close action.

Comment: think LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED worked in Compat 24.x, but the functionality has been changed in newer compat libraries and LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED now completely prevents the nav menu from showing, even via using the hamburger menu. Other solution is now needed.

Comment: Currently there is a bug with the method. I have reported it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136738274

Answer (score 23):

For `setDrawerLockMode()`, this is in the code but not on the  [Android developer](http://developer.android.com) docs:

```
/**
 * The drawer is unlocked.
 */
public static final int LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED = 0;

/**
 * The drawer is locked closed. The user may not open it, though
 * the app may open it programmatically.
 */
public static final int LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED = 1;

/**
 * The drawer is locked open. The user may not close it, though the app
 * may close it programmatically.
 */
public static final int LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN = 2;
```

Comment: And this now appears on dev docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I can still drag to open it.

Answer (score 3):

To disable the DrawerLayout gesture recognition use:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
```

Then, to enable right to left swipe, check this resource:
http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-gestures.html

Answer (score 3):

Look like I found bug. For example if set:

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

or

```
android:layout_gravity="left"
```

for drawer content and use `.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)` all will be fine.

But in case when `android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"` or something like it `LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED` will not work.

Comment: You are right. The reason is described well here by @A--C   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413116/why-i-cant-lock-drawerlayout-with-layout-gravity/18413276#18413276

Answer (score 3):

The `LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED` nowadays completely prevents the nav menu from showing, even via the hamburger menu (which may be unwanted). The following worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52160351/377320

Comment: I don't know but it is not working, I can still open it with a swipe gesture.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

You can expand the drawer by tapping the Hamburger icon or button from which you have to trigger. However, left-to-right swipe is no longer triggered.