# disable the swipe gesture that opens the navigation drawer in android

Tags: android, tabs, navigation, gesture, drawer

I've been following [the navigation drawer guide by Google](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and I'd like to add it to an Activity with tabs and gestures.

I'd like to disable the gesture to open the navigation drawer, does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 499, accepted):

You should use:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

It worked for me, the swipe to open the drawer was disabled.

If it still won't work, check out the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18413276/1708390).

Comment: Are you sure? I tried but it was diabled open and close, both.
I were testing on android 2.3x with ActionBarSherlock framework.

Comment: I'm sure because I've used it in my code. But I did not use with ActionBarSherlock. I used with ActionBar only.

Comment: To clarify: DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN locks the drawer to the open state so the user can't hide it. DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED locks the drawer to the closed state so the user can't open it. Lastly, DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED unlocks the drawer so it can be open or closed.

Comment: I have corrected the answer to LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED.

Comment: If you don't already have `mDrawerLayout`, set it as follows: `mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);`

Comment: But how about if we want to control the open/close with the app icon only, and not swiping? Is there a way to do that? I am curious because I'm trying to implement the new `ToolBar` (API 21) and use the `SlidingTabLayout` feature it has, which is conflicting with my Nav. drawer swiping. So I'd rather disable the Nav. drawer slide in favor of the `ToolBar` sliding feature.

Comment: Try overriding `onDrawerSlide()` in your `DrawerListener` and not calling the super method.

Comment: Also if you have two drawers on both sides you can lock one by getting the view of the NavigationView and doing `drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, navigationView)`

Comment: this disables the entire drawer (e.g. icon does not work anymore), not just swiping, hence did not answer the question -- which specifically referred to swiping

Comment: I think LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED worked in Compat 24.x, but the functionality has been changed in newer compat libraries and LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED now completely prevents the nav menu from showing, even via using the hamburger menu. Other solution is now needed.

Comment: Currently there is a bug with the method. I have reported it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136738274

Answer (score 135):

for locking you can do this:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

and for unlock :

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the accepted answer with the LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED flag

Comment: I think this is better than the accepted answer since it also introduces the opposing method

Comment: If I used mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED); for locking it closed the drawer so,
for locking i used  mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);

Comment: `error: cannot find symbol        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);`

Answer (score 15):

Add gravity value too when using [setDrawerLockMode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerLockMode(int));

Do this :

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, GravityCompat.END);
```

This should work like a charm

Comment: mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED); lock the both Drawer and drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, GravityCompat.END); represent which Drawer you want to lock thanks man it works for me and save my time.

Comment: In the current sources, it looks like 3 for left and 5 for right will work as expected, but GravityCompat.END does not.

Answer (score 13):

The answer to disable swiping is the correct one. I think LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED worked in Compat 24.x, but the functionality has been changed in newer compat libraries and LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED now completely prevents the nav menu from showing, even via using the hamburger menu.

The following class works for me (Kotlin):

```
class MyDrawerLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    ctx: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : DrawerLayout(ctx, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
      var isSwipeOpenEnabled: Boolean = true
  
      override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
          if (!isSwipeOpenEnabled && !isDrawerVisible(Gravity.START)) {
              return false
          }
          return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
      }
  
      @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
      override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
          if (!isSwipeOpenEnabled && !isDrawerVisible(Gravity.START)) {
              return false
          }
          return super.onTouchEvent(ev)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Gravity should be LEFT or RIGHT rather than START, END

Answer (score 8):

To disable swiping, override `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` on `DrawerLayout` and have them return false.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Let me elaborate on this a bit more in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, {Your drawer view});
```