# Open NavigationView only clicking on top-left icon but not with swype gesture

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I am implementing the navigation view in my app.

Actually, I can open it both clicking on "hamburger" icon (in my toolbar) and swypeing from left to right.

I want to open it only through the icon in my toolbar disabling the swype. Is it possible to do that?

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, sToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);

toggle.syncState();
```

EDIT

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED); // HERE
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, sToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);

toggle.syncState();
```

If I use the code above, where I used DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, I disable both icon and swype.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable the swipe gesture that opens the navigation drawer in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051104/disable-the-swipe-gesture-that-opens-the-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate. It's asking to keep hamburger icon enabled and disable left swipe gesture. I had the same question.

Comment: and how did you finally solve your problem?

Comment: did you find solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for my case

Lock it:

```
drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

And unlock it :

```
drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

Hope to help!

Comment: after initialize your drawer

Comment: If I use the code above, where I used DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, I disable both icon and swype.

Comment: hmm intresting .. did you have listener of drawer button for opening the layout

Comment: if you try to lock your drawer after toggle.syncState(); , did this change do the trick?

Comment: I have no listener to open the drawer. I'm not overriding DrawerListener.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106242/discussion-between-eldivino87-and-kristiyan-varbanov).

Comment: @KristiyanVarbanov , I have the same problem , would you mind sharing your chat result please?

Answer (score 1):

To make only the click work on the hamburger icon and not the swipe, i did the following,

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should also override onDrawerSlide and relock when the drawer is closed (slideoffset==0)...