# Horizontal Recyclerview in Navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer, android-navigation

I'm trying to implement a horizontal recyclerview in a Navigation Drawer. It works fine aside from the fact that when I swipe to the left, the Navigation Drawer gets closed. Is there a way to prevent the Navigation Drawer from closing just when the user interacts with the recyclerview? I tried this way:

```
    mNavigationRecyclerHourly.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: ");
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Recyclerview xml:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_navigation_hourly"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/progress_navigation_uv"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/thumb_navigation"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:padding="8dp">
                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17165256/2299040

Comment: Thanks, but then I can't close the Drawer when I swipe to the left.