# Is there any way of disable the swipe to open drawer in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, navigationview

Is there anyway to stop the swipe gesture from opening the drawer. I,ve tired:
drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)

However with this i can't even open the view by clicking the icon. I just need to disable the gesture that opens it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disable the swipe gesture that opens the navigation drawer in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051104/disable-the-swipe-gesture-that-opens-the-navigation-drawer-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this before open and close drawer. This work for me you can try it.

```
drawerLayout?.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
    
if (drawerLayout!!.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
     drawerLayout!!.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
} else {
     drawerLayout!!.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
}
```