# Why i can't lock DrawerLayout with layout gravity

Tags: android, listview, gravity, drawerlayout

I use DrawerLayout and recently i want to change gravity of listView in drawerLayout. But after i change gravity of listView to `android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"`from `android:layout_gravity="start"`, drawerLayout can't be lock to

```
mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

**setDrawerLockMode() work with;**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#F3F3F4"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >
</ListView>
```

**But it doesn't lock with;**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
    android:background="#F3F3F4"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >
</ListView>
```

`

Any clues of why can't I use lock mode with other gravities?

Thanks!

Comment: Also in order to handle the gravity check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50304856/2873702

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html), the *only* available gravities that can be used are `Gravity.LEFT`, `Gravity.RIGHT` or `GravityCompat.START`, `GravityCompat.END`.

(Emphasis mine):

> Drawer positioning and layout is controlled using the
>   android:layout_gravity attribute on child views corresponding to which
>   side of the view you want the drawer to emerge from: **left** or **right**.
>   (Or **start/end** on platform versions that support layout direction.)

Looking at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.java)

```
public void setDrawerLockMode(int lockMode, int edgeGravity) {
  final int absGrav = GravityCompat.getAbsoluteGravity(edgeGravity,
                                                       ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(this));
  if (absGrav == Gravity.LEFT) {
    mLockModeLeft = lockMode;
  } else if (absGrav == Gravity.RIGHT) {
    mLockModeRight = lockMode;
  }
  if (lockMode != LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED) {
    // Cancel interaction in progress
    final ViewDragHelper helper = absGrav == Gravity.LEFT ? mLeftDragger : mRightDragger;
    helper.cancel();
  }
  switch (lockMode) {
    case LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN:
      final View toOpen = findDrawerWithGravity(absGrav);
      if (toOpen != null) {
        openDrawer(toOpen);
      }
      break;
    case LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED:
      final View toClose = findDrawerWithGravity(absGrav);
      if (toClose != null) {
        closeDrawer(toClose);
      }
      break;
      // default: do nothing
  }
}
```

The method itself only checks if the gravity is `LEFT` or `RIGHT` (but uses a `GravityCompat` method, so `START` and `END` should be appropriately translated).

This would mean that by setting a gravity of `"start|bottom"`, you're introducing an invalid gravity, which causes `setDrawerLockMode()` to do nothing.

Comment: Thanks. I already fixed this problem adding list view into another layout. But this code explains my question.

Comment: You're welcome! Congrats on finding an alternative to what you wanted to achieve :-)

Comment: Correct answer, but they should also support `END` and `START`