# unlock drawer_layout when it is locked

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have a mainactivity where I have created a method to lock/unlock the drawer_layout and locked it in the `onCreate()` method.

```
public void disableDrawer(Boolean bol){
    if(bol) {
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    }else{
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    }
}
```

and after checking if the user is logged in or not i want to unlock the drawer from the fragment.
I tried to do this in onActivityCreated but the drawer is still locked

```
MainActivity activity = ((MainActivity)getActivity());
activity.disableDrawer(false);
```

in short

```
DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED
```

doesn't unlock `DrawerLayout`...

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should only use DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED or DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN, depending if you want your drawer to stay closed or opened.

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize toggle again.

toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);

After that, it unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a little.. nothing among other solutions in stackoverflow worked for me.
My specific problem was also that I was able to lock but not to unlock the DrawerLayout.

Then I saw in documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout#setdrawerlockmode) that there are two more functions:

```
void setDrawerLockMode (int lockMode, View drawerView)
void setDrawerLockMode (int resId, int edgeGravity)
```

The second one worked for me like a charm.

I simply specified the Gravity.LEFT parameter and now all is working perfectly.