# android studio, how to disable action bar menu opening on drag

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I wonder how to disable action bar menu opening on drag.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(getActivity() != null)
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(getActivity() != null)
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
}
```

I used this code to hide the bar in my fragment, but it still can be opened by dragging the left side of the screen.

Comment: here you can find what you are upto [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413116/why-i-cant-lock-drawerlayout-with-layout-gravity/18413276#18413276]
short story is this 
`mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
`